# How to watch multiple sub-directories with their own src and dist

Tags: sass, gulp

My current Gulp files correctly compiles src to dist for each project folder. The problem is, it doesn't actually **watch** for new changes after I run gulp watch.

**My  project directory:**

template-parts/blocks/{project-name}/**src**/css/*.scss

template-parts/blocks/{project-name}/**src**/js/*.js

template-parts/blocks/{project-name}/**dist**/css/*.scss

template-parts/blocks/{project-name}/**dist**/js/*.js

Here's my current Gulp file. 
Search for "Process, lint, and minify Sass files" to jump to the Scss task.

Any idea what I've done incorrectly? I've largely been following various guides and Stackoverflow posts to get where I am so far. I'm so close!

```
/**
 * Settings
 * Turn on/off build features
 */

var settings = {
    clean: true,
    scripts: false,
    polyfills: true,
    styles: true,
    svgs: false,
    images: false,
    copy: false,
    reload: false
};


/**
 * Paths to project folders
 */


var paths = {
    input: 'template-parts/blocks/**/src',
    output: 'template-parts/blocks/**/dist',
    scripts: {
        input: 'template-parts/blocks/**/*',
        polyfills: '.polyfill.js'
    },
    styles: {
        input: 'template-parts/blocks/**/scss/*.{scss,sass}',
        output: ''
    },
    svgs: {
        input: 'src/svg/*.svg',
        output: 'dist/svg/'
    },
    images: {
        input: 'src/images/*.{png,gif,jpg}',
        output: 'dist/images/'
    },
    copy: {
        input: 'src/copy/**/*',
        output: 'dist/'
    },
    reload: './dist/'
};


/**
 * Template for banner to add to file headers
 */

var banner = {
    full:
        '/*!\n' +
        ' * <%= package.name %> v<%= package.version %>\n' +
        ' * <%= package.description %>\n' +
        ' * (c) ' + new Date().getFullYear() + ' <%= package.author.name %>\n' +
        ' * <%= package.license %> License\n' +
        ' * <%= package.repository.url %>\n' +
        ' */\n\n',
    min:
        '/*!' +
        ' <%= package.name %> v<%= package.version %>' +
        ' | (c) ' + new Date().getFullYear() + ' <%= package.author.name %>' +
        ' | <%= package.license %> License' +
        ' | <%= package.repository.url %>' +
        ' */\n'
};


/**
 * Gulp Packages
 */

// General
var {gulp, src, dest, watch, series, parallel} = require('gulp');
var del = require('del');
var flatmap = require('gulp-flatmap');
var lazypipe = require('lazypipe');
var rename = require('gulp-rename');
var header = require('gulp-header');
var package = require('./package.json');

// Scripts
var jshint = require('gulp-jshint');
var stylish = require('jshint-stylish');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var uglify = require('gulp-terser');
var optimizejs = require('gulp-optimize-js');

// Styles
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var prefix = require('gulp-autoprefixer');
var minify = require('gulp-cssnano');
var tailwindcss = require('tailwindcss');

// SVGs
var svgmin = require('gulp-svgmin');

// Images
var imagemin = require('gulp-imagemin');


// BrowserSync
var browserSync = require('browser-sync');


/**
 * Gulp Tasks
 */

// Remove pre-existing content from output folders
var cleanDist = function (done) {

    // Make sure this feature is activated before running
    if (!settings.clean) return done();

    // Clean the dist folder
    del.sync([
        paths.output
    ]);

    // Signal completion
    return done();

};

// Repeated JavaScript tasks
var jsTasks = lazypipe()
    .pipe(header, banner.full, {package: package})
    .pipe(optimizejs)
    .pipe(dest, paths.scripts.output)
    .pipe(rename, {suffix: '.min'})
    .pipe(uglify)
    .pipe(optimizejs)
    .pipe(header, banner.min, {package: package})
    .pipe(dest, paths.scripts.output);

// Lint, minify, and concatenate scripts
var buildScripts = function (done) {

    // Make sure this feature is activated before running
    if (!settings.scripts) return done();

    // Run tasks on script files
    src(paths.scripts.input)
        .pipe(flatmap(function(stream, file) {

            // If the file is a directory
            if (file.isDirectory()) {

                // Setup a suffix variable
                var suffix = '';

                // If separate polyfill files enabled
                if (settings.polyfills) {

                    // Update the suffix
                    suffix = '.polyfills';

                    // Grab files that aren't polyfills, concatenate them, and process them
                    src([file.path + '/*.js', '!' + file.path + '/*' + paths.scripts.polyfills])
                        .pipe(concat(file.relative + '.js'))
                        .pipe(jsTasks());

                }

                // Grab all files and concatenate them
                // If separate polyfills enabled, this will have .polyfills in the filename
                src(file.path + '/*.js')
                    .pipe(concat(file.relative + suffix + '.js'))
                    .pipe(jsTasks());

                return stream;

            }

            // Otherwise, process the file
            return stream.pipe(jsTasks());

        }));

    // Signal completion
    done();

};

// Lint scripts
var lintScripts = function (done) {

    // Make sure this feature is activated before running
    if (!settings.scripts) return done();

    // Lint scripts
    src(paths.scripts.input)
        .pipe(jshint())
        .pipe(jshint.reporter('jshint-stylish'));

    // Signal completion
    done();

};

// Process, lint, and minify Sass files
var buildStyles = function (done) {

    // Make sure this feature is activated before running
    if (!settings.styles) return done();

    // Run tasks on all Sass files
    src(paths.styles.input, {base: "./"})
        .pipe(sass({
            outputStyle: 'expanded',
            sourceComments: true
        }))
        .pipe(prefix({
            AUTOPREFIXER: ['last 2 version', '> 0.25%'],
            cascade: true,
            remove: true
        }))
        .pipe(header(banner.full, { package : package }))
        .pipe(rename(function (path) {
            path.dirname += "/../../dist/css"
            }))
        .pipe(rename({suffix: '.min'}))
        .pipe(minify({
            discardComments: {
                removeAll: true
            }
        }))
        .pipe(header(banner.min, { package : package }))
        .pipe(dest("./"))

    // Signal completion
    done();

};

// Optimize SVG files
var buildSVGs = function (done) {

    // Make sure this feature is activated before running
    if (!settings.svgs) return done();

    // Optimize SVG files
    src(paths.svgs.input)
        .pipe(svgmin())
        .pipe(dest(paths.svgs.output));

    // Signal completion
    done();

};

// Optimize SVG files
var buildImages = function (done) {

    // Make sure this feature is activated before running
    if (!settings.images) return done();

    // Optimize SVG files
    src(paths.images.input)
        .pipe(imagemin())
        .pipe(dest(paths.images.output));

    // Signal completion
    done();

};

// Copy static files into output folder
var copyFiles = function (done) {

    // Make sure this feature is activated before running
    if (!settings.copy) return done();

    // Copy static files
    src(paths.copy.input)
        .pipe(dest(paths.copy.output));

    // Signal completion
    done();

};

// Watch for changes to the src directory
var startServer = function (done) {

    // Make sure this feature is activated before running
    if (!settings.reload) return done();

    // Initialize BrowserSync
    browserSync.init({
        server: {
            baseDir: paths.reload
        }
    });

    // Signal completion
    done();

};

// Reload the browser when files change
var reloadBrowser = function (done) {
    if (!settings.reload) return done();
    browserSync.reload();
    done();
};

// Watch for changes
var watchSource = function (done) {
    watch(paths.input, series(exports.default, reloadBrowser));
    done();
};


/**
 * Export Tasks
 */

// Default task
// gulp
exports.default = series(
    cleanDist,
    parallel(
        buildScripts,
        lintScripts,
        buildStyles,
        buildSVGs,
        buildImages,
        copyFiles
    )
);

// Watch and reload
// gulp watch
exports.watch = series(
    exports.default,
    startServer,
    watchSource
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow! I spent so much time trying to figure this out. Then 60 seconds after posting my question I just happened to figure it out.

Here's the fix:

I changed:

```
var paths = {
    input: 'template-parts/blocks/**/src'
```

to:

```
var paths = {
    input: 'template-parts/blocks/**/src/**'
```

That's it. Such a simple mistake.